# combine dataframes with overlapping indexes and different columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Suppose I'm given a large sets of csv files and I would like to read them into python and combine them in a certain way. Some key characteristics about the files

- Index is like a time dimension
- Column are specific entities
- Index of different files may be overlapping, but the value should be the same
- not all files have the same amount of columns

At the end I would like to have a huge data frame, collecting all entities over the whole time window.

Let me give an example

```
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data=[[np.nan, 2],[np.nan, 4],[np.nan, 8]],index = [0,1,2],columns=["A","B"])
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data=[[4, 8, 2],[4, 2, 8],[6, 1, 1]],index = [2,3,4],columns=["A","B","C"])
df_3 = pd.DataFrame(data=[[2, np.nan, 4],[8, np.nan, 8],[1, 8, 10]],index = [2,3,4],columns=["C","D","E"])
df_end = pd.DataFrame(data=[[np.nan, 2, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],[np.nan, 4, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],[4, 8, 2, np.nan, 4], [4, 2, 8, np.nan, 8], [6, 1, 1, 8, 10]],index = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],columns=["A","B","C","D","E"])
```

So as you see, we have three data frames and I envision to have the end result as outlined in `df_end`. In reality, the data frames are much larger but the toy example should make clear what I try to achieve.

I've tried to do something like this:

```
temp = pd.concat([df_1,df_2,df_3])
temp[~temp.index.duplicated(keep="first")]
```

which didn't show the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) in order of preference:

```
out = df_1.combine_first(df_2).combine_first(df_3)
```

Generalization with [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```
from functools import reduce

dfs = [df_1, df_2, df_3]
out = reduce(lambda a, b: a.combine_first(b), dfs)
```

Output:

```
     A  B    C    D     E
0  NaN  2  NaN  NaN   NaN
1  NaN  4  NaN  NaN   NaN
2  4.0  8  2.0  NaN   4.0
3  4.0  2  8.0  NaN   8.0
4  6.0  1  1.0  8.0  10.0
```

Alternative with [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
out = pd.concat([df_1, df_2, df_3]).groupby(level=0).first()
```